If the US joined WW1 on the side of the central powers and won, what would they have demanded in the treaty?
The question pretty much says it all. I was thinking about it and wondering what territory they'd demand, but then I realized they probably wouldn't demand territory, so then I wondered what they would demand. I'm no good at this, because I still think that the ending of Leviathan would have still had a war guilt clause, so I wanted to ask people who actually know. (Bit of context: This happened in a world where the Lusitania attack was a setup by the British navy and the US found out.)

What is the "ending of Leviathan"?

Why did USA join the war? Need to know that to answer the question. And as soon as I ask that, we know this is a story-based question, not a worldbuilding question. Vote to close.

Speculating about hypotheticals is not permitted on this site.

This is a question for Storytellers corner, not here.

I guess this is what I get for not asking in history stack exchange.

Just for reference, I doubt very much that History.SE will entertain a WI question at all! This just is not the kind of question SE is designed to answer.

Austria went to war because the Serbs had killed their crown prince. They basically had no strategic objectives other than making sure Serbia was never again in a position to do it again.
I am not saying that it Serbia was in fact responsible for killing the Austrian crown prince and his wife. That's a touchy subject. I am only saying that the Austrians were absolutely convinced that Serbia was responsible for the murder of Archduke Franz Ferdinand and his wife Sophie, Duchess of Hohenberg.
Germany went to war because they wanted to annex large tracts of Russian, Belgian, and French territory, and were lusting after French African colonies. Of all the powers engaged in WW1, Germany was the only one which actually had well-defined grand strategic objectives.
If the USA intervened on the side of the Central Powers they would have insisted on annexing Canada, or at least the habitable parts of Canada. Maybe also some English and French islands in the Caribbean and the British and French Guianas. There was nothing else they could take from any of the powers of the Entente. I really don't see why the USA would have bothered with annexing any part of the inhospitable and very sparsely populated Russian Far East.
Of couse, there would have been a large war indemnity to be paid by the losers.
And no, there would not have been any war guilt clause in the peace treaty.
In the actual peace treaty which ended WW1 there was no war guilt clause. That was a creation of the irresponsible press and the (mostly German) rabble rousers. The language of the treaty only says that "Germany accepts responsibility of Germany and her allies causing all the loss and damage," which was actually true: the war ended with the German army occupying Belgium and a large part of northern France; the Entente powers (almost) never set foot on German territory during the war, so quite obviously all the loss and damage had indeed been done by the German army.
